# Webstorm Angular NullInjectorError

Tags: angular, typescript, components, webstorm

I am trying to run this code but I keep getting this error in console:

```
main.ts:6 ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[Department -> Department -> Department]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for Department!
    at NullInjector.get (core.mjs:7493:27)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:7914:33)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:7914:33)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:7914:33)
    at ChainedInjector.get (core.mjs:12084:36)
    at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (core.mjs:3201:39)
    at getOrCreateInjectable (core.mjs:3246:12)
    at Module.ɵɵdirectiveInject (core.mjs:10041:12)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.DepartmentComponent_Factory [as factory] (department.component.ts:12:33)
    at getNodeInjectable (core.mjs:3431:44)
main.ts:7 NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[Department -> Department -> Department]: 

  NullInjectorError: No provider for Department!
    at NullInjector.get (core.mjs:7493:27)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:7914:33)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:7914:33)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:7914:33)
    at ChainedInjector.get (core.mjs:12084:36)
    at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (core.mjs:3201:39)
    at getOrCreateInjectable (core.mjs:3246:12)
    at Module.ɵɵdirectiveInject (core.mjs:10041:12)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.DepartmentComponent_Factory [as factory] (department.component.ts:12:33)
    at getNodeInjectable (core.mjs:3431:44)
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'BlockchainSimulation';
}
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<app-blockchain></app-blockchain>
```

**department.ts:**

```
export class Department {
  name: string;
  description: string;

  constructor(name: string, description: string) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
  }
}
```

**block.ts:**

```
import { Department } from "./department";

export class Block {
  department: Department;
  message: string;
  status: boolean;

  constructor(department: Department, message: string, status: boolean) {
    this.department = department;
    this.message = message;
    this.status = status;
  }
}
```

**blockchain.ts:**

```
import { Block } from "./block";

export class Blockchain {
  blocks: Block[] = [];

  constructor() { }

  pushToBlockchain(block: Block) {
    this.blocks.push(block);
  }

}
```

**testDepartment.ts**

```
import { Department } from "./department";

export const Factory = new Department("Factory", "Makes things");
export const Supplier = new Department("Supplier", "Supplies things");
```

***Components:***

**department.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
// import { _the_specific_department } from '';
import { Department } from "../department";
import { Factory, Supplier } from "../testDepartment";
import {Block} from "../block";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-department',
  templateUrl: './department.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./department.component.css']
})
export class DepartmentComponent {
  @Output() sendEvent = new EventEmitter<Block>();

  department: Department;
  block!: Block;

  constructor() {
    this.department = Factory;
    this.block = {} as Block;

  }

  createBlock(message: string, status: string) {
    this.block.department = this.department;
    this.block.message = message;
    this.block.status = ( status == 'true' );
    this.sendBlock();
  }

  sendBlock() {
    this.sendEvent.emit(this.block);
  }



}
```

**department.component.html:**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="createBlock(message.value, status.value)">
  <label>Message: <textarea #message></textarea></label>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input id="true" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="true" name="true" #status>
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="true">Male</label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input id="false" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="false" name="false" #status>
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="false">Female</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

**blockchain.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Blockchain } from "../blockchain";
import {Block} from "../block";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-blockchain',
  templateUrl: './blockchain.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./blockchain.component.css']
})
export class BlockchainComponent {
  blockchain: Blockchain;

  constructor() {
    this.blockchain = new Blockchain();
  }

  pushToBlockchain(block: Block) {
    this.blockchain.pushToBlockchain(block);
  }

}
```

**blockchain.component.html**

```
<app-department (sendEvent)="pushToBlockchain($event)"></app-department>
```

I looked through the internet for hours but couldn't find a solution. I tried setting up a new workspace, reinstalling packages, debugging my code but nothing works!

Comment: Consider https://angular.io/guide/creating-injectable-service#creating-an-injectable-service-1 - your `Department` class is not decorated with `Injectable`. That's what jumps out to me!